# Docker creates two images

Tags: docker

I am starting with the docker and its concepts. I have read official Guide on how to create [images](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/), and managed to create several images (proud).

Now I actually wanted to build an MySQL server, so I can connect it with my application. For that purpose, I have found official MySQL [Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/fc3e856313423dc2d6a8d74cfd6b678582090fc7/5.6/Dockerfile).

The thing is, when I run it with:

> docker build -t mysql .

It creates two images:

1. First one has debian as Repository and stretch-slim as a TAG. Size is 55MB
2. Second has none for both. Size is 65MB.

I am now confused. Why two images? My understanding was it will be one image with Debian and MySQL, but not two.

Some guideline are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the expected behavior:

As you can read in the first line of the *docker-library-bot* file from MySQL [Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/fc3e856313423dc2d6a8d74cfd6b678582090fc7/5.6/Dockerfile) is says:

```
FROM debian:stretch-slim
```

As per Docker [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#format):

> A Dockerfile must start with a `FROM` instruction. The FROM
>   instruction specifies the Base Image from which you are building.

A [base image](https://docs.docker.com/glossary/?term=base%20image) is an image that has no parent.

So, as a result you will have two images:

1. **debian** -> Base Image
2. **mysql** -> Image created from the Base Image with mysql and all the software needed to run it.

Comment: So to have MySQL instance, I should run the second image, not the Debian one?

Comment: Would you happen to know, how can I give that image a name? Currently it has none for Repository and Tag

Comment: take a look to the docker tag [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/tag/) it may help you

Answer (score 1):

If your Dockerfile has a **FROM** image, it has a dependency on another image, so It will download and generate all the dependant images.

If you need to create a **BASE IMAGE** you can do it by using a special image called *scratch* as a parent image.

i.e:

```
FROM scratch
ADD hello /
CMD ["/hello"]
```

For more information about how to create a base image: 
https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/baseimages/#create-a-simple-parent-image-using-scratch